# How to open Access from the taskbar?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I had being reviewing the forum and trying several ideas but still have the problem. I am running Access 2013, in a form I hit a button to spell and grammar check a text field. The check is done properly using the Word Grammar check. So far so good. But, once Word is closed I activate Access but it stays blinking in the taskbar and I have to click on it to continue working. I want Access back into the screen to continue working as normal.

The code is the following:

```
Private Sub Comando2_Click()

Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

accessid = GetCurrentProcessId
accesshwnd = Application.hWndAccessApp

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With objWord
       Set doc = .Documents.Add
       .Selection.Text = Me.Texto0
       docum = doc & " - Word"
       .Visible = True
       VBA.AppActivate (docum)
       .Visible = False
       .Dialogs(wdDialogToolsSpellingAndGrammar).Show
       If Len(.Selection.Text) <> 1 Then
          Me.Texto0 = .Selection.Text
'          spellcancell = False
       Else
'          spellcancell = True
       End If
       doc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
    .Quit
End With

Set objWord = Nothing

AppActivate (accessid)
SetForegroundWindow accesshwnd


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help Regards

As mentioned above, I want Access back into the screen to continue working as normal. I have tried to activate it by Hwnd, SetForegroundWindow and lots of other ideas read in the forum... nothing worked

Comment: Yu might need to add `sleep ...` like is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835809/how-can-i-bring-my-current-access-db-to-foreground-via-vba.   This is because Windows makes the program that sends output to the screen for the last time the active window, so before doing `SetForegroundWindow accesshwnd` you have to wait (a short time) before Word is closed, and then activate Access.

Comment: @Luuk thanks but still same problem.  It seems to work if the second app is opened by shell. I will try to see if I can open word with shell and pass the test to check

Comment: Couldn't you just use `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling` in Access?  Something like this link:  [spell-check-code-in-ms-access-form-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784221/spell-check-code-in-ms-access-form-field-throws-error-when-change-is-accepted)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, tried that and it works, but only check the spelling not the grammar. I need the grammar validation. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround, it is not ideal, but at least it works till I get a better solution.

Thanks for your help, made me think in a differet way:

```vb
    AppActivate GetCurrentProcessId 
    SendKeys "%{TAB}", True 
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making it a bit too complicated, and do close all objects.

This runs as expected:

```vb
    Dim objWord     As Word.Application
    Dim doc         As Word.Document
    
    Dim docum       As String
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    With objWord
        Set doc = .Documents.Add
        docum = doc.Name & " - Word"
        .Visible = True
        VBA.AppActivate docum
        .Visible = False
        
        .Selection.Text = Me.Texto0
        .Dialogs(wdDialogToolsSpellingAndGrammar).Show
        If Len(.Selection.Text) <> 1 Then
        Me.Texto0 = .Selection.Text
'          spellcancell = False
        Else
'          spellcancell = True
        End If
        
        doc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
        Set doc = Nothing
        .Quit
    End With

    Set objWord = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks I have tested two scenarios, 1) changing all my programin by yours but the access is not even being activated to blink in the taskbar 2) substituting the piece of my code handling word by yours, in that case it work exactly like mine, access stay blinking in the taskbar

Comment: Well, this code runs here, so something else is going on.

Comment: Hi @Gustav you give a clue of why is working wrongly, unfortunately this is not giving me the solution, I am using a Surface, it works in PC mode as well as Tablet mode. You are right working on PC mode is correct, however working in Tablet mode is not. I need it to work in Tablet mode.

Comment: That explains. I'll see if I can locate a Surface.

Comment: Hi @Gustav, thanks for making me to think in a different way, pls see my answer for a workaround